# Format abstracts as unnumbered chapters

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, abstract

I'm writing master thesis and working on LaTeX template for the successors ...

The standard of the university requires abstract in every language to be formed as unnumbered Chapter:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
...
\chapter*{Résumé}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Résumé}
...
```

Is it possible to customize the `abstract` environment (or to use other workaround) to be able to write:

```
{
\selectlanguage{russian}
\begin{abstract}
    This is ABSTRAAAAACT!!!
\end{abstract}
}
{
\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{abstract}
    This is ABSTRAAAAACT!!!
\end{abstract}
}
```

So that the titles would still appear in the ToC as unnumbered chapters?

P.S. I'm using the `report` class

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. I removed the "thanks" from your post, since we do not include it. You can thank the answerers by up-voting and acepting their answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just makes abstract include a chapter named with the command `\abstractname`, which is provided by `babel` and is re-defined for each language.

The `lipsum` package and `\lipsum` command are used only to provide some dummy text.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

%% START HERE %%
\def\abstract{
  \chapter*{\abstractname} % start chapter
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname} % table of contents line
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\abstractname}}{} % header mark
}
\def\endabstract{\clearpage}
%% END HERE %%

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{french}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Solution suggested by @tohecz worked perfectly...